# Generics and Functional programming in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, generics

The two variants of the sum function below are my attempt to repeat the lisp version introduced by Abelson and Sussman in the classic "Structure and interpretation of Computer Programs" book in Swift. The first version was used to compute the sum of integers in a range, or the sum of squares of integers in a range, and the second version was used to compute the approximation to pi/8.

I was not able to combine to the versions into a single func which will handle all types.  Is there a clever way to use generics or some other Swift language feature to combine the variants?

```swift
func sum(term: (Int) -> Int, a: Int, next: (Int) -> Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    if a > b {
        return 0
    }
    return (term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b))
}

func sum(term: (Int) -> Float, a: Int, next: (Int) -> Int, b: Int) -> Float {
    if a > b {
        return 0
    }
    return (term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b))
}
```

with

```swift
sum({$0}, 1, {$0 + 1}, 3)
```

6 as result

```swift
sum({$0 * $0}, 3, {$0 + 1}, 4)
```

25 as result

```swift
8.0 * sum({1.0 / Float(($0 * ($0 + 2)))}, 1, {$0 + 4}, 2500)
```

3.14079 as result

Comment: How about Struct / Enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it a bit easier I have changed the method signatures slightly and assume that it is good enough to work for `func sum_ <T> (term: (T -> T), a: T, next: (T -> T), b: T) -> T {`, where T is some kind of number.

Unfortunately there is no `Number` type in Swift, so we need to make our own. Our type needs to support

- addition
- comparison
- `0` (the neutral element for addition)

#### New Protocols for the requirements of the function

Comparison is handled in the `Comparable` protocol, for the reset we can create our own protocols:

```
protocol NeutralAdditionElementProvider {
    class func neutralAdditionElement () -> Self
}

protocol Addable {
    func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

#### `sum` implementation

We can now implement the `sum` function:

```
func sum <T where T:Addable, T:NeutralAdditionElementProvider, T:Comparable> (term: (T -> T), a: T, next: (T -> T), b: T) -> T {
    if a > b {
        return T.neutralAdditionElement()
    }
    return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)
}
```

#### Making `Int` and `Double` conform to the protocols

`+` is already implemented for `Double` and `Int` so protocol conformance is easy:

```
extension Double: Addable {}

extension Int: Addable {}
```

Providing a neutral element:

```
extension Int: NeutralAdditionElementProvider {
    static func neutralAdditionElement() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

extension Double: NeutralAdditionElementProvider {
    static func neutralAdditionElement() -> Double {
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Sebastian, thank you so much for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for, clever.

Answer (score 3):

Sebastian answers your question (+1), but there might be other simple functional solutions that leverage existing generic functions (such as `reduce`, which is frequently used for `sum`-like calculations). Perhaps:

```
let π = [Int](0 ..< 625)
    .map { Double($0 * 4 + 1) }
    .reduce(0.0) { return $0 + (8.0 / ($1 * ($1 + 2.0))) }
```

Or:

```
let π = [Int](0 ..< 625).reduce(0.0) {
    let x = Double($1 * 4 + 1)
    return $0 + (8.0 / (x * (x + 2.0)))
}
```

These both generate an answer of `3.14079265371779`, same as your routine.

---

If you really want to write your own generic function that does this (i.e. you don't want to use an array, such as above), you can simplify the process by getting the `+` operator out of the `sum` function. As Sebastian's answer points out, when you try to perform addition on a generic type, you have to jump through all sorts of hoops to define a protocol that specifies that the types that support `+` operator and then define these numeric types as conforming to that `Addable` protocol.

While that's technically correct, if you have to define each numeric type that you might use in conjunction with this `sum` function as being `Addable`, I'd contend that this is no longer in the spirit of generic programming. I'd suggest you rip a page out of the `reduce` book, and let the closure that you pass to this function do the addition itself. That eliminates the need to need to define your generics as being `Addable`. So that might look like (where `T` is the type for the sum that will be calculated and `U` is the type for index that is being incremented):

```
func apply<T, U: Comparable>(initial: T, term: (T, U) -> T, a: U, next: (U) -> U, b: U) -> T {
    let value = term(initial, a)
    if a < b {
        return apply(value, term, next(a), next, b)
    } else {
        return value
    }
}
```

And you'd call that like so:

```
let π = apply(Double(0.0), { return $0 + 8.0 / Double((Double($1) * Double($1 + 2))) }, 1, { $0 + 4}, 2500)
```

Note, it's no longer a `sum` function as it's really just a "repeat executing this closure from `a` to `b`", hence my choice to rename this to `apply`.

But as you can see, we've moved the addition into the closure we pass to this function. But it gets you out of the silliness of having to redefine every numeric type you want to pass to the "generic" function as being `Addable`.

Note, this also addresses another problem that Sebastian solved for you, namely the need to implement `neutralAdditionElement` for every numeric data type, too. That was necessary to perform a literal translation of the code you provided (i.e. to return zero if `a > b`). But I've changed the loop such that rather than returning zero when `a > b`, it returns the calculated `term` value if `a == b` (or greater).

Now, this new generic function can be used with any numeric types, without needing to implement any special functions or make them conform to any special protocols. Frankly, there's still room for improvement here (I'd probably considering using a `Range` or `SequenceType` or something like that), but it gets to the your original question of how to use generic functions to calculate the sum of a series of evaluated expressions. To make it behave in a truly generic manner, the answer is probably "get the `+` out of the generic function and move it to the closure".

Comment: Very good point about `Addable` and the like not being in the right spirit. Addition for integers and addition for floats *are not the same operation*, so attempting to hide that fact behind a generic interface exposes users of that interface to undefined behavior. Swift is about avoiding undefined behavior—hence the no implicit conversion between numeric types, etc.

Comment: Great answer, Rob! @rickster: How is addition any different than other functions defined in protocols?

Comment: @Sebastian: that might be worth a whole answer... guess I'll post one.

Comment: Rob, Sebastian, rickster, your respective answers shed so much insight on the question above.  Indeed it all boils down to a matter of type-safety.

Comment: The two variants of the sum func differ only in the type signature of the function arguments, the body of the functions is exactly the same in both variants.  It seems that the only reason this is working is because the return 0 branch of the if statement implicitly converts the literal 0 to the desired return type.  If not for that implicit conversion it would be necessary to convert the constant 0 explicitly to the type returned by the function.  I believe this implies that the Addable approach would not have worked if not for the implicit conversion. Please let me know if you agree.

Comment: The approach taken by @Rob of separating the creation of the sequence from applying the closure to the elements of the sequence and encapsulating the addition in the closure avoids the type issue.  The difficulty with this approach is that it is no longer as clear just by reading the code that this is an implementation of Summation (as in Capital Greek Sigma).  Indeed the Apply approach is more general of which Summation is a specific case.

Comment: @zrocky Re: `Addable` requiring some implicit conversion, I would not characterize it that way. Here's my view: A generic rendition of `sum` needs to call certain functions for certain parameters, and because it knows nothing about the generic parameter types, it uses protocols to dictate what functions can be called on which parameters. You're comparing `a` and `b`, so those have to be `Comparable`. The `sum` is calling `+` function, so that has to be `Addable`. And you're returning zero, so it also must conform to `NeutralAdditionElementProvider` (e.g. `Zeroable`; lol).

Comment: Bottom line, Sebastian showed you one way to do exactly what you asked for. I tried to show you how you might pull those context-specific functions out of `sum`, yielding a more generic function and to bypass the need for all of these new protocols altogether. And rickster provided a little more context on some of the issues involved.

Comment: yes, great responses, I (now) know I'm not supposed to say th...k y.. so you get the idea :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090804/957768) has a decent way to make this "work" for a simple test case. However, as [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29091525/957768) notes, something like an `Addable` protocol isn't quite in the spirit of functional programming (or of Swift in general, perhaps). Those solutions are both workable, so this answer will get more into the "spirit" issue.

Let's tell a tale of four operators:

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
func +(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
func +(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func +(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String // See note below
```

Which of these have the same behavior? "Well, obviously the first three are the same," you might say, "and the last one is different: `1 + 1 = 2` regardless of whether you're dealing with `Int` or `Int32`, and that of course means the same thing as `1.0 + 1.0 = 2.0`. But `"1" + "1" = "11"`, so adding strings is completely different."

These assumptions are incorrect — all four operators have different behavior.

What happens when you add `1` and `2_147_483_647`? (Let's ignore the `String` case for now — I think we can all agree that string concatenation is different from numeric addition. [Right, JavaScript?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)) It depends on what type those values are, and possibly on other things, too.

- If both are `Int`... well, are you compiled for a 32-bit or 64-bit CPU? `Int` is aliased to `Int32` on 32 bit and to `Int64` on 64 bit. Just got a shiny new iPhone 6? Great, your answer is `2_147_483_648`.
- If both are `Int32` (or if you're compiled for 32-bit)... well, `2_147_483_647` is the largest possible signed 32-bit integer, so adding one to it produces an overflow. In Swift, adding with the `+` operator traps on overflow, so you crash. Swift forces you to think about whether you want overflow behavior (by choosing the `+` or `&+` operator) so you don't [blow up your rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure).
- If both are `Float`, you get `2.14748365E+9`. But wait, what's `Float(2_147_483_648)`? That's also `2.14748365E+9` — adding one did nothing! The IEEE 32-bit float format has 24 bits of mantissa, so if you add two numbers that differ by more than 2^24, there's not enough precision to store the result — the least significant digits vanish. And that's just the beginning of all the [wild](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29637/Five-Tips-for-Floating-Point-Programming) and [wooly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) issues you can get into with floating-point arithmetic.

So what's the upshot of all this? Why are we splitting hairs over when addition is really addition?

Each operator in Swift is a separate function because each has different behavior — to put a finer point on it, each defines a specific *contract* regarding its behavior. You know that when you add two `Int32` values, the sum must be representable as an `Int32` or you'll [trap](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzpirates.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2008%2F10%2Fackbar.jpg&f=1), and that you have to do things differently if you need to handle overflow cases. You know that when you work with `Float`s, all arithmetic is subject to precision issues. The contracts defining those types determine these things.

Swift specifically, and strongly-typed functional(-ish) programming languages in general, tend to have a strict notion of types and the contracts that go with them, and strict rules about when you're using specific types. The idea here is [*type safety*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) — always knowing what types you're dealing with helps you (and the compiler) reason about the contracts those types define.

When you unify `+` operators behind an `Addable` protocol, you're hiding the differences between those types. Sure, you can use that to make some short functions that work on all sorts of types. But at the cost of replacing strictly defined types with a fuzzy type... and the more you use fuzzy types, the less sure you can be about what your code will do with them in all cases.

---

<sup>**Note:** this operator isn't actually in the Swift library — I've simplified it here for brevity. Addition of `String`s is actually performed by a generic operator that applies to all types implementing the `ExtensibleCollectionType` protocol, of which `String` is one.</sup>

Comment: by all means please post your answer to Sebastian's comment, looking forward to further insight.