# What protocols do all numbers conform to in Swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, double, protocols

I am trying to figure out what protocols in Swift make it so I have a function that only takes *Numbers*.  I want to be able to pass `Int` and `Double`, `Float` and `Float`, pretty much any combination of *Numbers*.

```
func takeNumbers(A: Protocol1, Protocol2, B: Protocol1, Protocol2) {

}
```

I just listed two protocols I don't know if it I need 1,2,3, etc.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29089966/957768) for both some answers on *how* to make multiple numeric types conform to the same protocols, and some on *why* it's probably better not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create your own protocol and extend each type to conform to it?

Further, you could use a protocol extension to implement a common method to get the value of each. For instance, you could return an int value from each by implementing `switch` logic on the type.

Also, you said `Float` twice.

Comment: Yeah I meant like pass Int and Double or pass 2 Floats

Comment: Ah I see now - well my advice still stands. You can look at the docs to see all the protocols that numbers conform to, but you're probably better off making your own protocol.